# Are determinants forms?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I am reading "Linear Algebra" by Hoffman and Kunze.

A determinant is defined as multi-linear alternating **function** which maps sq. matrices on a ring $K^{n\times n}$ to the ring $K$ itself.
[ch 5, pg 144]

It is unambiguous that determinants are functions after all.

There is another notion of a (linear) function space defined as (a linear subspace of) a set of all maps among a set of linear spaces. [ch 3, pg 75]

Is it fair to speak of this (linear) function space as a linear space in itself?

Further, we are met with this notion of linear functionals (forms), that are maps from a linear space to the field over the space. [ch 3, pg 97]

I am thinking if determinants could be thought of as linear forms? I understand the definition holds for fields and not rings. But, conventionally, determinants are over real and complex field.
If so, would it unlock other concepts of forms for our determinants?

- Determinants being the dual space of the linear function space among vector spaces.
- Determinants of maps collapsing to nullspace possessing properties of annihilators?

Comment: *But, conventionally, determinants are over real and complex field* -  I thought it is a group homomorphism $\det\colon GL_n(K)\rightarrow K^{\times}$ where $K$ is an arbitrary field. For coding theory and cryptography it is very popular to consider finite fields $K$, for example. So the determinant is a map (a homomorphism even), and a multilinear form.

Comment: If you're willing to introduce exterior algebra, you can observe that the determinant is just the trace of the top exterior power of a matrix, and the trace is a linear form. This can be a useful perspective, but it's just factoring out the multilinearity into the exterior product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The" determinant (denoted $\det$) is a function from $K^{n\times n}$ to $K$, where $K$ is a commutative ring (often $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, but there are many other choices) and where $n$ is a nonnegative integer. So its input is an $n \times n$-matrix with entries in $K$, and its output is an element of $K$. There is one such function for each choice of $K$ and $n$.

The determinant of a matrix $A$ (denoted $\det A$) is the value of this function at $A$.

Functions from a given set to a vector space do themselves form a vector space (with pointwise addition and scaling). So, yes, you can view the function $\det : K^{n \times n} \to K$ as a vector in the vector space of functions from $K^{n \times n}$ to $K$. This viewpoint is occasionally useful but not, by itself, insightful. In particular, there are **lots** of functions from $K^{n \times n}$ to $K$. If $\det$ was a **linear** function, then we could get some more out of this, but alas it is not (unless $n = 1$). Thus, in particular, nullspaces and dual spaces are not relevant here.

What is true is that $\det$ is a **multilinear** function, at least if we rewrite its input (originally a matrix) as an $n$-tuple of column vectors (or row vectors). This viewpoint is quite fruitful and can be used to give slick proofs for the basic properties of determinants. See, for example, Section 9C of [Sheldon Axler, *Linear Algebra Done Right*, 4th edition 2024](https://linear.axler.net/LADR4e.pdf) (I think this is not in the earlier editions).

Comment: Allow me to reflect on your answer. Linearity and multilinearity are two different things. "The" determinant is definitely multilinear always but is linear for very few special cases. Like when two maps are almost similar but vary at a single dimension. Discarding the multilinear idea in lieu of this determinant as a vector idea will do more harm than good. The idea of determinant as a form is permissible but limiting and misleading.

Comment: The word "form" is not as specific as you seem to think it is: It typically means a map to the base field $K$, but the domain of a map can be a vector space or a product of spaces. Thus, there are both linear forms and multilinear forms. The determinant $\det$ is a multilinear form. Unfortunately, multilinear forms are not as well-behaved as linear ones, so there is not much that can be derived from this (but together with alternatingness, multilinearity is useful: see Section 9C in Axler).

Comment: Would a inner product defined on an inner product space be a linear form in this regard? A functional is just any structure to its base field right?

Comment: An inner product would be a bilinear form if you are working over $\mathbb R$, and a sesquilinear one if you are working over $\mathbb C$ (because of the conjugation on one of its arguments).